# How to fill browser auth popup with credentials selenium php

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[image: browser auth popup]

i trying to fill this popup using selenium in php
i tried this

```
$driver->get("http://example.com");
$driver->wait(10);
$driver->action()->sendKeys('username');
```

but nothing filled

and got this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Facebook\WebDriver\Interactions\WebDriverActions::sendKeys() must be an instance of Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverEle
ment or null, string given, called in C:\wamp64\www\new\test.php on line 87 and defined in C:\wamp64\www\new\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Interactions\WebDriverActions.
php:269
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Answer (score 1):

when you are doing `get()` make sure to pass creds as well.

```
$driver->get("http://UserName:Password@Example.com");
```

make sure to use sendKeys like this :

```
$driver->get("https://www.google.com/ncr");
$driver->manage()->window()->maximize();
sleep(5);
$element = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::name("q"));
$element->sendKeys("LambdaTest");
```

**Update :**

```
// use this expected condition to switch the control to alert

$driver->wait()->until(WebDriverExpectedCondition::alertIsPresent());
$driver->switchTo()->alert()->sendKeys('username' + Keys.TAB + 'password');
$driver->switchTo()->alert()->accept();
```

**Update 2:**

```
 $driver->wait()->until(WebDriverExpectedCondition::alertIsPresent());
 $driver->switchTo()->alert()->sendKeys('username');
 $driver->getKeyboard()->pressKey(WebDriverKeys::TAB);
 $driver->switchTo()->alert()->sendKeys('password');
 $driver->switchTo()->alert()->accept();
```

Comment: i tried this but it asks for credentials to can access site also

Comment: See you are using sendKeys like this `$driver->action()->sendKeys('username');` but you need to have web locater to send the keys right ? otherwise you would need to switch to alert and then send the keys

Comment: Cool but how i can select the inputs in popup ?

Comment: i'm relay appreciate your time , but for this until(WebDriverExpectedCondition::alertIsPresent())
it wait too long time and not fill anything , so i tried to remove it and add 1 sec wait time , and got this error  Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverException::throwException(27, 'no such aler
t'

Comment: @Mohamed : Can you do right click on that pop up and inspect element ? Does that show anything in developer tool.

Comment: i found nothing , just blank page

Comment: so that must be an alert.. remove ` $driver->wait()->until(WebDriverExpectedCondition::alertIsPresent());` and try the update 2 code and let me know the error

Comment: yes but this alert , the browser which pushing it not the html body

Comment: yeah alert won't be there in HTML body it will be a JS code running for client side validation

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your "Sign in" popup is Chrome's Basic Authentication popup. That's not an "alert" box nor is it an actual HTML element, so you can't use sendKeys() to send keystrokes to it.

cruisepandey's $driver->get("http://UserName:Password@Example.com") suggestion should work, though. Note, I think these days, "http://UserName:Password@Example.com" only works in Selenium; it doesn't work as a URL directly in the Chrome address bar.